# The pod with the sleeping astronauts

Tags: oblivion

**Regarding the pod that returned Julia and the other hyper-sleeping astronauts to Earth.**

Why had Jack not noticed suspended animation capsules with the names of himself and Vicka?

Surely they were not expected to stay out of suspended animation for the majority of the journey to Titan. He was in a rush the first visit (especially after finding Julia), but you'd think he would have taken more time to look around when they returned for the black box. Or of course Julia might just have pointed it out with an *"I'll explain later"*.

Speaking of the 2nd visit, why had the Tet not immediately sent drones to reduce the pod to rubble<sup>1</sup> after the first visit, in order to destroy all the evidence that might make Jack even more suspicious than he already was?

It remarked when he visited it that he had been disobeying orders for some time - so it had its suspicions of him.

1. Or at least 'more drones' after Jack destroyed the one that had killed most occupants, and was about to kill Julia.

---

In lieu of a sourced answer, I will give the tick to the most plausible answer presented.

Comment: Is the answer "Because it's a very badly written film"?

Comment: @Richard  Good to see you did not enter that as an answer.  I was led to believe that this site encourages speculation as to how it *might* have made sense.  I could propose an answer, but not one that even I find very convincing.  I was hoping someone with a little more ..imagination might come up with something better.

Comment: There seem to be two separate questions running here.

Comment: @Richard  True, but they are closely related (I think).  Further, when I was proposing asking 21 separate questions about Oblivion, someone suggested that was 'spamming the site'.  I'll leave them together for now, but if the consensus is they are different enough to warrant separate questions, I'll split the 2nd one off.

Comment: The answer to every one of those 22 questions is "Because it's a very badly written film"

Comment: @Richard I do agree on the 'badly written'.  But have since scanned the list with the newer understanding (gained from discussions on this site) that the Tet was really just a [Berserker Probe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berserker_%28Saberhagen%29) & the entire 'gathering deuterium' simply a smoke screen to justify the presence of the Jack's and Vicka's to maintain the killer drones.  In that light, it reduces my list of 'What the huh?' questions from 21 to ..just 6. :)  You've already provided a possible answer for 1, and I have proposed an answer to another of those 6 remaining questions.

Comment: The irony is, of course, that my answers are very well written.

Comment: @Richard  The irony was not lost on me.  ;)  And yes, it is a good answer.  :)

Comment: We have no evidence that Vicka and Jack _had_ hibernation pods, do we? I don't see why we need to jump to calling the movie "badly written"; I really don't think it was.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  That possibility was mentioned in the answer I wrote.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yes, I can read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as the pod question is concerned, we never see Jack's pod and even if he did see it, there's no reason to think that just because he sees his surname (Harper) on the pod that he'd immediately jump to the conclusion that he was a clone who'd had his memory erased by an alien species in order to subjugate humanity and that his entire life was a lie.

[image: Oblivion Pod]

Answer (score 3):

I will add an answer to this.

1. The Tet possibly had some drones visit the pod after the first visit, do a basic inventory (in which the flight recorder was missed) and decided it contained nothing inherently harmful to itself (weapons, lots of fissile material, a space going capability). The Tet probably felt that reducing the pod to rubble might have been a clear sign of its involvement, as the Scavs might have stolen bits and pieces of the pod, but would not have completely destroyed it.
2. As to the 2nd part of the question, we don't really know how long it was expected to take to get to Titan, it might have been a journey of only a few months.  If Jack and Vicka were 'flight crew' where the rest were 'science team', it was probably felt that it was advantageous for the two flight crew to be ready to respond to an in-flight emergency at a moment's notice, hence keep them out of hyper-sleep for the journey both ways.  So the *main* reason they had the science team in hyper-sleep was to conserve food, water and oxygen (presuming they used a lot less in the hyper-sleep state).

Comment: 3. It's quite possible that both pilots' pods were located in the forward section, since they would be the first one to wake from hibernation.